# Getting First Child in XSLT Transform

Tags: xslt

I have the following XSL, which I use to transform Oracle SQL developer's XML format to the "full" XML format expected by DBUnit (for creating data sets for testing).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:java="java"
    xmlns:dbutil="com.jason.util.DatabaseTestUtil">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;dataset&gt;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;table name=""&gt;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:for-each select="RESULTS/ROW">
                <xsl:for-each select="COLUMN">
                    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;column&gt;</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@NAME" />
                    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/column&gt;</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="RESULTS">
                <xsl:for-each select="ROW">
                    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;row&gt;</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:for-each select="COLUMN">
                            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;value descriptor="</xsl:text>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@NAME"/>
                            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">"&gt;</xsl:text>
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="@NAME='NAME'">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="dbutil:generateRandomName()" />
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="@NAME='MEMBER_SSN'">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="dbutil:generateRandomSsn()" />
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="@NAME='SPOUSE_SSN'">
                                    <xsl:variable name="spouseSsn">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="." />
                                    </xsl:variable>
                                    <xsl:if test="dbutil:hasSpouseSsn($spouseSsn)"><xsl:value-of select="dbutil:generateRandomSsn()" /></xsl:if>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="@NAME=E_MAIL_ADDRESS">
                                    <xsl:text>noname@mail.com</xsl:text>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/value&gt;</xsl:text>
                            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/row&gt;</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/table&gt;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/dataset&gt;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have a call to some "backend" java so that I don't have people's private information embedded in my test sets.

Unfortunately, the first loop through /RESULTS/ROW should only be a loop through the columns of the first child of /RESULT/ROW.

Can anyone tell me how to get that first child?

Comment: Your XSLT looks horrible. If you need to create a result element you can simply use a literal result element e.g. `<xsl:template match="/"><dataset>...</dataset></xsl:template>`, there is no need to use disable-output-escaping. As for accessing the first child, if you use `/RESULT/ROW[1]`, you are selecting only the first `ROW` child. Or `/RESULT/ROW/*[1]` would select the first child element of any name of all `ROW` children of the root `RESULT`.

Comment: It may be ugly, but it works. I ended up creating a variable named firstChild and putting RESULTS/ROW[1] into it, and iterating over that.

Comment: Why are you manually constructing all the tags using `&lt;dataset&gt;`? That almost entirely defeats the purpose of using XSLT.

Comment: Mainly because I didn't know what I was doing, and at this point I don't want to rewrite what was meant to be a quick and dirty utility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Unfortunately, the first loop through /RESULTS/ROW should only be a
>   loop through the columns of the first child of /RESULT/ROW.
>
> Can anyone tell me how to get that first child?

**Replace**:

```
        <xsl:for-each select="RESULTS/ROW">
            <xsl:for-each select="COLUMN">
              .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  
           </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

**with**:

```
        <xsl:for-each select="RESULTS/ROW[1]/Column">
              .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  
        </xsl:for-each>
```